# Keras LSTM Larger Feature Overwhelm Smaller Ones?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I've had this suspicion for the longest time but couldn't figure out whether the case or not, so here's the scenario:

I'm trying to build a model that has 3 features from 3 different inputs:

1. A text sequence
2. A float
3. A float

Now all three of these makes up one time step. But since I'm using glove to vectorize my text sequence using 100 dimensions, a 20 word text sequence ends up having the length of 2000. Hence, the overall input per step has the length of 2002 (each time step a matrix with the shape (1, 2002) is fed in, with 2000 of those coming from a single feature.

Is the text sequence overwhelming the two floats so whatever the value of the floats are it's irrelevant to the prediction? If so, what can I do to fix this? Perhaps manually weigh how much each feature should be used? Code is attached

```
def build_model(embedding_matrix) -> Model:
    text = Input(shape=(9, news_text.shape[1]), name='text')
    price = Input(shape=(9, 1), name='price')
    volume = Input(shape=(9, 1), name='volume')

    text_layer = Embedding(
        embedding_matrix.shape[0],
        embedding_matrix.shape[1],
        weights=[embedding_matrix]
    )(text)
    text_layer = Dropout(0.2)(text_layer)
    # Flatten the vectorized text matrix
    text_layer = Reshape((9, int_shape(text_layer)[2] * int_shape(text_layer)[3]))(text_layer)

    inputs = concatenate([
        text_layer,
        price,
        volume
    ])

    output = Convolution1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(inputs)
    output = MaxPool1D(pool_size=4)(output)
    output = LSTM(units=128, dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True)(output)
    output = LSTM(units=128, dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True)(output)
    output = LSTM(units=128, dropout=0.2)(output)
    output = Dense(units=2, activation='linear', name='output')(output)

    model = Model(
        inputs=[text, price, volume],
        outputs=[output]
   )

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

    return model
```

Edit: note that the input shape into the lstm is (?, 9, 2002) which means right now the 2000 coming from the text are treated as 2000 independent features

Comment: Have you normalized the values of those two float features?

Comment: Yeah I have, everything’s between 0 and 1. However I don’t think that’s the issue here, the problem is out of 2002 columns passed in per time step, 2000 of them are from the text

Comment: Have you tried a two branch model, one branch for processing text and another one for processing those two features? Plus, in your current model, does the loss decrease or not during training?

Comment: Huh what do you mean by a two branch model? If I put in a lstm layer before all three features before concatenating them together isn’t that just using lstm as a feed forward network? And also since right now there’re 9 time steps in total and while for the two floats it’ll be alright, the text for each step is exactly the same. What would be the use of using lstm for processing them? (The text has 9 different time steps that are the same so at each step the text can be interpreted with the floats)

Comment: Loss is decreasing rather slowly and jaggedly but I’m worried that it’s just using the text and not using the floats

Comment: One branch processes the text and another branch processes the two features and then the result of these two branches are merged. However, you mentioned the text is the same in all of the 9 timesteps? Then why do give it to an LSTM then? Although it may not be a bad thing to do so, but have you tried a simpler approach first?

Comment: Good point, yeah I get that but the reason I had for them all going into lstm is because since there’re 9 times steps, with lstm I can make sure the text is included when predicting each step of the two floats data (since the output is gonna be the two floats at t+1)

Comment: I don't get your point. The last dense layer consists of 8 units. So it does not (only) output two floats at (t+1).

Comment: Oh apologies, yeah you’re right on that, the final dense layer should’ve been 2 units instead of 8, typo there. Nonetheless the point is still that at each time step I want the text to be taken into consideration as well as the two floating points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, one approach is to have a two branch model where one branch processes the text data and another one processes the two float features. At the end the output of the two branches are merged together:

```
# Branch one: process text data
text_input = Input(shape=(news_text.shape[1],), name='text')

text_emb = Embedding(embedding_matrix.shape[0],embedding_matrix.shape[1],
                weights=[embedding_matrix])(text_input)

# you may alternatively use only Conv1D + MaxPool1D or
# stack multiple LSTM layers on top of each other or
# use a combination of Conv1D, MaxPool1D and LSTM
text_conv = Convolution1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(text_emb)
text_lstm = LSTM(units=128, dropout=0.2)(text_conv)

# Branch two: process float features
price_input = Input(shape=(9, 1), name='price')
volume_input = Input(shape=(9, 1), name='volume')

pv = concatenate([price_input, volume_input])

# you can also stack multiple LSTM layers on top of each other
pv_lstm = LSTM(units=128, dropout=0.2)(pv)

# merge output of branches
text_pv = concatenate([text_lstm, pv_lstm])

output = Dense(units=2, activation='linear', name='output')(text_pv)

model = Model(
    inputs=[text_input, price_input, volume_input],
    outputs=[output]
)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

As I have commented in the code, this is just a simple illustration. You may need to further add or remove layers or regularization and tune the hyper-parameters.